# Using while loop for sqldatareader

Tags: c#, while-loop, sqldatareader

I trying to get both **policeid** and **fullname** from my table named **PoliceAccount** when the **handle** column equal to the value of the dropdownlist and then put the value into a label and display it. By using the code provided below I keep getting the result of the last row data of **policeid** and **fullname**. However, my table contain of 2 police account which having the column **handle** equal to the value of the dropdownlist. Do help me out. THANKS!

```
conn.Open();
sql = "Select policeid, fullname From PoliceAccount Where handle = '"+ ddlReportDateTime.SelectedValue +"'";
    using (var cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            String policeid = dr.GetString(0);
            String fullname = dr.GetString(1);
            String result = policeid + " " + fullname;
            lblAssignTo.Text = result;
        }
    }
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you got to put the value into a collection (list or so):

```
    var myData = new List<string>();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        String policeid = dr.GetString(0);
        String fullname = dr.GetString(1);
        String result = policeid + " " + fullname;
        myData.Add(result);
    }
```

and then use it as you want - display the first/last/concatenated/etc....

EDIT:

display the concatenated string:

```
    yourLabel.Text = myData.Aggregate((x,y)=> x + "; " + y);
```

Comment: how do I get all the result out and display it onto a label?

Comment: myData is the list of strings you retrieved from database. to display them all in a concatenated string - see the edit part